Does fama-french factors apply 1-day delay between their portfolio formation and the trade? If so, why?
I'm currently replicating fama-french 5 factors using price and financial data.
I applied 1-day delay in calculating daily portfolio returns of factors, which assumes June-end portfolio to be traded on close price(precisely, total return index) of July 1st.
However, correlations between my replicated factors and official fama-french factor returns are higher when I remove the delay.
So I'm guessing that fama-french use 0-day delay in their portfolio return calculation.
I'm confusing because it seems not a good assumption of real investment or trading scenario for we usually can't trade a security on close price after the market closed.
Q1. Is there any good reason for using 0-day delay in making factors ?
Q2. Is it more common to use 0-day delay in academic ?

The purpose is to understand how stocks are priced in the market, not to test an investment strategy, so there is no delay. If you do use the results for an investment portfolio you would have to consider delays, commissions, etc,
